# what is the difference between ViewModelProvider constructors

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-components

I am learning about ViewModel and I was wondering is there any difference between theses methods to get a `ViewModelProvider` instance?

**method A:**

```java
ViewModelProvider viewModelProvider = new ViewModelProvider(getViewModelStore(),
                ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication()));
mViewModel = viewModelProvider.get(NoteActivityViewModel.class);
```

**method B:**

```java
mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteActivityViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [`ViewModelProvider(ViewmodelStoreOwner)` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner)):

> This method will use the [default factory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory#getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()) if the owner implements [`HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory). Otherwise, a [`ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory) will be used.

And as per the [Lifecycle 2.2.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0) (which was when that constructor was added):

> You can pass a `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity` to the new `ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner)` constructor to achieve the same functionality when using [Fragment 1.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0).

And the [Fragment 1.2.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0) state that:

> `SavedStateViewModelFactory` is now the default factory used when using `by viewModels()`, `by activityViewModels()`, the `ViewModelProvider` constructor, or `ViewModelProviders.of()` with a Fragment.

So `new ViewModelProvider(this)` uses `SavedStateViewModelFactory`, which provides everything that `AndroidViewModelFactory` provides in addition to support for the [Saved State module for ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate).

There would be no reason to use the `ViewModelProvider` with one of the standard factories when using Fragment 1.2.0 or higher - that constructor would only be useful if you have your own custom factory.